# How to read csv files from s3 bucket using Pyspark (in macos)?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read csv df from s3 bucket , but facing issues. Can you let me know where am I masking mistakes here ?

```
conf=SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('local')
conf.setAppName('sparkbasic')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf) 



sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "abc")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "xyz")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
```

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider")

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "mybucket/path/fileeast-1.redshift.amazonaws.com")


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('sparkbasic').getOrCreate()
```

### This is the code where I get the error

```
csvDf = sc.read.csv("s3a://bucket/path/file/*.csv")
```

### This is the error I get , I tried links given in stackoverflow answers , but nothing worked me so far

ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look to [S3Fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Given your details, maybe a configuration like that could work:

```py
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(client_kwargs={'endpoint_url': 'fileeast-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
"aws_access_key_id": "abc",
"aws_secret_access_key": "xyz"})
```

To check if you manage to interact with s3, you can try the following command (NB: change `somefile.csv` to an existing one)

```py
fs.info('s3://bucket/path/file/somefile.csv')
```

Note that in `fs.info` we start the path with `s3`. If you do not encounter an error, you might hope the following command works:

```py
csvDf = sc.read.csv("s3a://bucket/path/file/*.csv")
```

This time you have the path begins by `s3a`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 's3fs'

Comment: TypeError: create_client() got multiple values for keyword argument 'aws_access_key_id'

Comment: I made suggested changes , still this error persists                                            
  TypeError: create_client() got multiple values for keyword argument 'aws_access_key_id'